# CoffeeScript compiler throws ClassCastException

Tags: compiler-errors, coffeescript, netbeans-plugins

I am new to CoffeeScript and maybe I am doing something strange, but I get a ClassCastException when I try to compile the following CoffeeScript Code:

```
if 1 == 1 then
  alert 'Thats always true'
```

If i write it in the following form:

```
if 1 == 1 then alert 'Thats always true'
```

it works... Is there some syntax-error? Even if thats the case I would never expect an internal compiler error if I make any syntax error...

I am using the NetBeans CoffeeScript Plugin.
Here is the Exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
>       at coffeescript.nb.CoffeeScriptRhinoCompiler.compile(CoffeeScriptRhinoCompiler.java:59)
>       at coffeescript.nb.CoffeeScriptAction$CompilerTask.compile(CoffeeScriptAction.java:236)
>       at coffeescript.nb.CoffeeScriptAction$ConsoleOutputCompileTask.run(CoffeeScriptAction.java:193)
>       at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `then` with block-level code.

```
if 1 == 1
    alert 'Thats always true'
```

As for the exception, it must be a bug in the plugin or NetBeans itself. The CoffeeScript compiler correctly shows an "unexpected POST_IF" error.

Comment: That's solving the issue... But the compilererror is still strange... Maybe it's just Murphy's law :-)